# Android fragments navigation and backstack

Tags: android, navigation, android-fragments, back-stack

I have a header bar (kinda like menu) and 4 fragments (MAIN, A, B, C) from which the MAIN should be 'main/root' fragment for backstack.

Problem i have is when user via menu goes for example MAIN > A > B > C. 
If i simply use backstack it will go in reverse order which i don't want.
I need back button to go back to MAIN no matter how user navigated to one of those 3.

[image]

My current code (which is wrong, it quits app when not in MAIN and current fragment is switched from other non-MAIN fragment) looks like this:

```
private void SwitchFragment(Fragment pFragment)
{
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_fl_fragmentcontainer, pFragment);
    if (_CurrentFragment == _Frag_Main)
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

    _CurrentFragment = pFragment;
}
```

Comment: looks like You are adding only main fragment to back stack and not the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your stack must contains 2 fragments at maximum

Main is visible
Main is onBackstack / AorBorC is visible.
User click on back ==> Main is visible.
User click on back ==> application end

I suppose A / B / C are displayed in the same view so in this case,

When user click on your Menu, you have to check if A/ B / C is currently displayed and replace it by the one selected by the user.

```
private void displayFragment(Fragment pFragment) {
    Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.main_fl_fragmentcontainer);        
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.main_fl_fragmentcontainer, pFragment);
    if (_CurrentFragment == _Frag_Main) {
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    ft.commit();    
    _CurrentFragment = pFragment;
}
```

can override `OnBackPressed` method of your activity.